# What do you call a rising sequence of short notes in a composition esp with strings?

Tags: music, score

I have a noticed in a few pop songs you occasionally get a series of notes that sounds like a set of short notes rising in succession - usually done with strings. One example is in Abba's Dancing Queen, right after the lyric 'and when you get the chance..' you get this sequence I am thinking of. Another example is the very beginning of 'One in a Million' by the Pet Shop Boys.

Is there a musicological term for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glissando.  Although I can't help feeling this question is a bit off topic.

Comment: great..thanks! its more musicology i agree but I am using it for an effect rather than as part of the main melody..if that makes sense

Answer (score -1):

It's know as Mannheim rocket.

http://www.talkclassical.com/5102-mannheim-rocket.html